# Get the last element of an array, without changing its internal pointer

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get the last element of an array without changing its internal pointer?

What i'm doing is:

```
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {  
    //do stuff  
    if($condition) {  
        //Here I want to check if this is the last element of the array            
        prev($array);  
    }  
}
```

so `end($array)` would mess things up.

Comment: Hint: `array_keys`.  Also, click the big orange question mark to get formatting help and instructions.

Comment: @PankitKapadia `end()` changes the arrays internal pointer, and it's mentioned in the question that it isn't of any help.

Comment: use `$count = count($array);` and check using it.

Comment: @xyu - check the answer. is it what you want? :-/

Comment: Does that array may contain associative keys (keys with not just integers but also strings)?

Comment: No. If you noticed - the array pointer is changed within the loop, so a counter is not a suitable solution.

Comment: @brunoais No. But the indexes are neither sorted, nor sequential.

Comment: "so end($array) would mess things up." Not if you use it like I did. Also consider and check to see if my code is better than the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: this accepted answer is outdated and now triggers the following error.** The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) for the `end()` specifically says that function's parameter *is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.*

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

It's simple, you could use:

```
$lastElementKey = end(array_keys($array));
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {  
    //do stuff  
    if($key == $lastElementKey) {  
        //Here I want to check if this is the last element of the array            
        prev($array);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the solution in the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490818/get-the-last-element-of-an-array-without-changing-the-array-in-php)

Comment: Not sure how that answer applies but ok

Comment: The answer provided in that other question wont work for you if your array contains the same value more than once. The correct way is to check the keys and not the values.

Comment: My solution uses no if's so I suppose that it is faster.

Comment: It does the job (the array has distinct values).

Comment: The first line has moved the internal pointer for the array, has it not?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$totalelements = count($array);
$count=1;

while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {  
    //do stuff  
    if($count == $totalelements){ //check here if it is last element
        echo $value;
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can be done like `for($count=1;list($key, $value) = each($array));$count++)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using something like:

```
$lastElement= end($array);
reset($array);
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {  
    //do stuff   
}

// Do the extra stuff for the last element
```

Comment: not a good solution if the first and last elements are the same. The correct solution is to use the array keys.

Comment: I wanted to check if `$value` is the last element.

Comment: @xyu ? Why doesn't it work? From what I understood, you wanted to check it to do something else with it, right? You want to do the same thing for all elements except the last one where you want to do some extra stuff

Comment: It does. I never said it doesn't.

Comment: Oh... ok. I thought that you were writing like that because it wasn't a solution for the problem you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
$l = each($array);
$lastKey = $l['key'];
$array = array_reverse($array, true);

while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {  
    //do stuff  
    if($key == $lastKey) {  
        echo $key . ' ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }  
}
```

The problem here is that if the array is big one then it'll take some time to reverse it.